# .Json not reading a line of the text file

Tags: c#-4.0

**the problem is that the DOB is not taking any values from the text file, when I print out the DOB it does not give me the date of birth of the subjects that I have in the text file.
This code is in C# with the framework “Newtonsoft.Json”.** Please help

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
namespace Ejercicio_1
{

    //MoviStar class
    public class MovieStar
    {
        //variables to store data
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
        public string sex { get; set; }
        public string nationality { get; set; }

        /// Calculate Age 
        
     
        
            public int calcAge() 
       {
            int daynow = int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
            int dob = int.Parse(DOB.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));

            int ans= (daynow - dob) / 10000;
            return ans;

        }



    }
}
```

**MovieStarDriver:**

```
  using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Ejercicio_1
{
    internal class MovieStarDriver
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // used StreamReader to read file content
            StreamReader s = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Mengueche\Documents\Task_1\input.txt");
            string jsonString = s.ReadToEnd();

            // objects list of MovieStar class
            List<MovieStar> objs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MovieStar>>(jsonString);

            // iterate through the list of objects and display results
            foreach (MovieStar star in objs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(star.name + " " + star.surname);
                Console.WriteLine(star.sex);
                Console.WriteLine(star.nationality);
                Console.WriteLine(star.calcAge() + " years old");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to put the text file.

Comment: If you forgot the text file then please edit your question and add it in, instead of just writing a comment saying you forgot it.